# How does react know which components have been updated?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

```js
import React from 'react';

const App = () => {
  console.log('app render');

  return (
    <div>
      <Children />
    </div>
  );
};

const Children = () => {
  const [update, setUpdate] = React.useState(false);

  console.log('children render');

  return (
    <div>
      <button onClick={() => setUpdate(!update)}>update</button>
    </div>
  );
};

export default App;
```

Above code, at first, two messages are printed out 'app render' and 'children render.'
Then, when I click the update button, a message is printed 'children render'.

I learned the following rules when I started to learn `React` at beginning.

1. when props are updated
2. when states are updated
3. when the parent component is updated

I've been working on `React` Projects well since then.
Today, somehow, I got a question.

How does react know which components have been updated?

`setUpdate` tells `React` that `Children` is updated?

I think I can understand that `React` can notice the props changing.
because, if `render` functions are called, it means they can know whether props of their children are changed or not.

But I don't understand how `react` recognizes state-changing.

Comment: `setUpdate tells React that Children is updated?` Yes, that is the entire purpose of the setUpdate function. Calling a setState function tells react "change this state, and rerender". Does that answer your question or is there some additional info you're looking for?

Answer (score 2):

The components form a tree. In the first render, the React framework renders from the root node. Any component functions that call `useState` will have the set state function registered and associated with the component instance. In the future, if you call a set state function, the React framework finds the associated component instance to re-render the sub-tree.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. That is `React` can know which component is called from the dispatch, right?
+ How does `Redux` know what are states  associated with what components from `useSelector`?